# Renaming raw_input() into input() in python 3 (version detection)

Tags: python

I want to have an uniform way of using input over python <3 and >=3.
Is there any cleaner way to do it apart of of version detection:

```
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    raw_input("Press Enter to continue...");
else:
    input("Press Enter to continue...");
```

Comment: Slightly cleaner using the same idea is to have at the top of the file:
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    input = raw_input

Comment: Yes, sure in production; I wanted clearly to express my doubts :)

Answer (score 3):

The [`six`](http://pythonhosted.org/six/) or [`future`](http://python-future.org/) libraries will more or less take care of this (and many other cross-version concerns) for you.